# Can someone tell me what this small chunk of js code is doing?

Tags: javascript

I program in different languages, but not in javascript. I can kind of tell what the code in the rest of the program is doing, but I don't understand this part. If anybody can help me out that would be great.

```
    log: {
        content: "<div id='exp1_div'></div><div id='exp2_div'></div><div id='exp3_div'></div>",
        onLoad: function() {
            $('#exp1_div').html("Experiment 1: " + log["exp1"]);
            $('#exp2_div').html("Experiment 2: " + log["exp2"]);
            $('#exp3_div').html("Experiment 3: " + log["exp3"]);
        },
        keyHandler: doNothing
    }
```

Someone claims that I broke their program. What the program is supposed to do is finish an experiment and write the results in a log file. I fixed everything else, but I can't figure out the log file part. I.e. where is the log file? What is the name of the log file? Etc.

Comment: This code doesn't actually do *anything*, it simply defines an object with some properties. There is no log file, there are a few divs on the page that will be filled with whatever the value of `log["exp1"]` etc. are whenever `log.onLoad()` is called.

Comment: I would guess that the part you show is nested within another object literal. If so, it is creating a property `log` in the outer object that is referencing the object you show that has three properties: `content` - a string of html, `onLoad()` - a method, and `keyHandler` - most likely a reference to a function `doNothing` defined elsewhere (I don't _know_ that `doNothing` is a function, it just seems likely - but it might be a variable). If it is _not_ part of some other object then it would be a syntax error because `log:` would be a label in front of a block that has invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content: "<div id='exp1_div'></div><div id='exp2_div'></div><div id='exp3_div'></div>"
```

It is creating 3 div's exp1_div, exp_2_div, exp3_div.

```
$('#exp1_div').html("Experiment 1: " + log["exp1"]);
```

It is then selecting the individual div and filling its inner HTML with a corresponding entry from an array (not listed in this snippet). The array has elements "exp1", "exp2", and "exp3".

Comment: Hmm, thanks. So all that's missing is a log file being written at the end of the experiment, but it doesn't seem like the file is being written to in this javascript file. There is also a jquery.js file, but that has hundreds of lines of code. Someone said I should look into jquery. What exactly is jquery?

Comment: Log is not an array, it's an object... This object.

Comment: @user1234672 jQuery is one of the very best and very famous JavaScript libraries which greatly improves website development. Some people believe that there is no JavaScript without jQuery. :) Look at their website: http://jquery.com/ and try it out!

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library... just a big set of functions to make doing common things easier

Comment: The code snippet as shown is _not_ creating the three divs, it is just putting the markup for them (as a string) into a property of the object. Presumably there is some other method that actually uses that to create the divs in the DOM.

Comment: @AutoSponge - `log` isn't that object, because within the snippet `log` appears to be the property of some other object that isn't shown in which case it couldn't be accessed directly as `log[...]`, it would need to be `otherObj.log[...]` (if the snippet started `log=` instead of `log:` you'd be right).